# Type 'ChildNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLOptionElement'

Tags: typescript

This is my method:

```ts
public deleteSelectOption( index: number ): void {
  this.elements.lyricsLineSelect.forEach( ( el: HTMLSelectElement )  => {
    el.childNodes[ index ].remove();
    el.childNodes.forEach( ( option: HTMLOptionElement, i: number ) => {
      if( i >= index ){
        option.value = i.toString();
        option.textContent =  `${ i + 1 }. ${ this.lyrics[ i ].text }`;
      }
    } );
  } );
}
```

I'm getting this error when trying to iterate through el.childNode using forEach loop:

```
Argument of type '(option: HTMLOptionElement, i: number) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: ChildNode, key: number, parent: NodeListOf<ChildNode>) => void'.
Types of parameters 'option' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'ChildNode' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLOptionElement': defaultSelected, disabled, form, index, and 190 more.ts(2345)
```

How to let typescript to know that `el.childNodes` is an array of `HTMLOptionElement` ?

Comment: To answer the last sentence of your question, you should be able to do `(el.childNodes as HTMLOptionElement[]).forEach(...)`

Comment: Your suggestion still rise an error, but ( el.childNodes as NodeListOf<HTMLOptionElement> ) works! Thanks!

Comment: Nice! You should post that answer and accept it for future people who google a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to replace this line

```
el.childNodes.forEach( ( option: HTMLOptionElement, i: number ) => {
```

to this

```
( el.childNodes as NodeListOf<HTMLOptionElement> ).forEach( ( option: HTMLOptionElement, i: number ) => {
```